# Static var lost its value after exit a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 5.5, and I met this problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WhatTheHell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int testVal;

    void Awake()
    {
        SetVal(testVal);
        Debug.Log(testVal);
    }

    void SetVal(int val)
    {
        val = 10;
    }
}
```

The debug result is 0 insted of 10. why?

Comment: the `static` variable `SetVal` is never initialized explicitly in your code and hence has its default `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are defining the `testVal` as `static` so it will be available in all methods inside the class(you can access them outside the class as well through the class name that is `WhatTheHell.testVal`). So actually there is no need for passing the variable in this case.

Then you are passing the variable `testVal` to the `SetVal()` method as pass by value, so it will pass the value only not the actual variable. that is why the change is not reflected the actual variable.

The following code will work as you expected:

```
public static int testVal=0;

void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log(testVal); // print 0
    SetVal();
    Debug.Log(testVal); // print 10
}

void SetVal()
{
    testVal = 10;
}
```

For more detailed explanation and example you can take a look into the [Story of Pass By Value and Pass By Reference in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037209/Story-of-Pass-By-Value-and-Pass-By-Reference-in-Cs) by Ehsan Sajjad.

Answer (score 3):

you can perform this operation as multiple ways by making *Global variable* , *ref Keyword* or simple *return int* from function. as describe

**Global Variable**

```
public static int testVal=0;

void Awake()
{
    SetVal();
    Debug.Log(testVal); // print 10
}

void SetVal()
{
    testVal = 10;
}
```

**ref Keyword**

```
public static int testVal=0;

void Awake()
{
    SetVal(ref testVal);
    Debug.Log(testVal); // print 10
}

void SetVal(ref int testVal)
{
    testVal = 10;
}
```

**return int**

```
public int testVal=0;

void Awake()
{
    testVal = SetVal();
    Debug.Log(testVal); // print 10
}

int SetVal()
{
    return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that int is a value type and not a reference type.

When you pass 'testVal' to 'SetVal()', it make a copy of the value of 'testVal' into 'val' just for the method scope.

If you use the keyword ref, 'val' argument will be handle as a reference type

```
void SetVal(ref int val)

SetVal(ref testVal);
```

More about value and reference types here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To avoid other mistakes of this type I would encourage you to read this: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html the

Comment: It's definitely not the type of article you'd normally read about but understanding the stack will help you understand why your first example didn't work. Also I just feel it's good to know in regards to understanding the load you're putting on the computer when programming a certain way.